# Intermediate SQL query search (Database Systems MSU)

Tags: sql

**Find the average age of employees for each department where every employee is 30 years old or younger. Please list the corresponding department id as well.**

This is how the table is structured:

> Employee(eid:integer, ename:string, age:integer, salary:real)
>
> Works(eid:integer, did:integer, pct_time:integer)
>
> Department(did:integer, dname:string, budge:real, managerid:integer)

[omp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vFTb.jpg)

Comment: BTW, an age column will be out of date every year. Bad design, store year of birth instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    Select department, avg(age) from
     Employee group by department 
      having count(distinct employee) =
       Sum(case when age<=30 then 1 
           else 0 
          end)
```